# ASP.NET pages taking too long to load

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, load, timeout

I'm working on a WordPress site right now and I have a few ASP.NET pages that I'm linking to in a different directory on the site. I'm using the latest version of WordPress and .NET 4 Integrated.

Right now when I click on one of the ASP.NET pages it is taking about 30 seconds to load. This also caused the web request to time out.

Any ideas what might be causing this to happen? Thanks.

Comment: It's because you're using asp.net. On a serious note, can you provide some code or the function of said files?

Comment: @KorvinSzanto the WordPress site is at the root and the ASP.NET pages are in a directory that is at the root.

Comment: Alright, so what are the asp.net pages doing? If they are looping through all the numbers `1 to 144 * 10^234` it's easy to say why it's taking forever.

Comment: It's hard to say what's taking so long, probably if you get a much faster server, the page processing will get faster, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet if you don't have access to the source for the ASP.NET content is trying to enable tracing on those pages using the web.config, or to use some external resource like the Y!Slow FireFox add-in.  See the link for enabling tracing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx